# Why struct linux_dirent members ( d_name, d_reclen, .. ) always getting 0?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems, kernel-module

This is for educational purposes and I'm new in kernel programming. 
I'm trying to override sys_call_table[__NR_getdents] with my custom function. The goal of my custom function is to read all the files of my current directory. In [man-pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html), it says that **d_name** is the file name and **d_reclen** is the size of the struct. Form the example code and googling, I understand that to get the next file name, I need to add d_reclen (offset) with the existing structure obj. Keep looping will give me the list of all files in the current directory. Please do correct if understanding is flawed.

However, this is not happening. Here is my Structure,

```
struct linux_dirent {
unsigned long   d_ino;
unsigned long   d_off;
unsigned short  d_reclen; 
char        d_name[];
};
```

Here is my custom function to replace sys_call_table[__NR_getdents]

```
asmlinkage int ( *orig_getdents )(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent __user *dirent, unsigned int count);

// Custom function
asmlinkage int sys_getdents_new(unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent __user *dirent, unsigned int count) {

struct linux_dirent *retn;
//  unsigned long Records;
int Records, RemainingBytes;
unsigned short length;
Records = (*orig_getdents)(fd, dirent, count);
//printk(KERN_INFO "Inside sys_getdents_new : %d", Records);
//printk(KERN_INFO "dirent lenght : %hu", dirent->d_reclen);

if (Records <= 0){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Record is 0 or less");
    return Records;
    }

// allocating retn (with the size of Record), in kernel memory
retn = (struct linux_dirent *) kmalloc(Records, GFP_KERNEL);


// coping the content of dirent --> (to) --> rent
copy_from_user(retn, dirent, Records);


printk(KERN_INFO "retn->d_reclen %hu", retn->d_reclen);
printk(KERN_INFO "retn->d_name %s", retn->d_name);  


RemainingBytes = Records;
int i=100;
// As retn->d_reclen always yields 0, RemainingBytes remains the 
same causing infinite loop
//  while(RemainingBytes > 0){
while(i > 0){

        RemainingBytes -= retn->d_reclen;      
        printk(KERN_INFO "RemainingBytes %d   \t File: %s " ,  RemainingBytes , retn->d_name );

    retn = (struct linux_dirent *) ((char *)retn + retn->d_reclen);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Next decrease from RemainingBytes %d " ,  retn->d_reclen);
    i--;

  }

// Copy the record back to the origional struct
//copy_to_user(dirent, retn, Records);
//kfree(retn);


return Records;
```

}

Here is the dmesg log that I'm getting.

```
[   66.825638] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825638] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825639] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825640] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825640] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825641] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825642] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825642] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825643] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825644] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825644] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825645] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 

............
[   66.825778] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825779] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825781] Record is 0 or less
[   66.825820] retn->d_reclen 0
[   66.825821] retn->d_name 
[   66.825821] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825822] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
[   66.825823] RemainingBytes 80     File:  
[   66.825823] Next decrease from RemainingBytes 0 
........
```

As you can see, all the members of the **linux_dirent** are showing 0 which is not expected. Therefor inside while loop nothing is changing. Any Idea what I did wrong? Please help

Comment: What does mean _r_ as in argument of _kmalloc()_? Where do you **fill** that memory? Where do you check errors?

Comment: @0andriy In my understanding, each file is returned as a struct, therefore, Using kmalloc to allocate memory for that structure(I found this while googling). This is basically the return of the function. I use **dmesg**  to see what's going on in the background.

Comment: Read what I asked again carefully, read documentation on _kmalloc()_, please.

Comment: @0andriy sorry. I misunderstood. **r** is the size of the struct  **linux_dirent**. I use this size with **kmalloc** to allocate same amount of memory in the kernel. I just saw that I allocate kernel memory into **retn** but I did not put anything into it. I thought this was the issue. So, I used `copy_from_user(retn, dirent, r);` to copy **dirent** into **rent**. But still same problem

Comment: @Tsyvarev Here is the full source code (https://pastebin.com/nSBsdqNX) and here is the dmesg log (https://pastebin.com/i3aYAY8r)

Comment: What you are trying to copy **from** user? What are you trying to do exactly? The code has now more problems (existing ones + this weird `copy_from_use()` one).

Comment: @0andriy, I'm trying to read all the files in the current directory

Comment: @0andriy, can you please give me an outline, what could I do differently?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Done.